# Reading DOMDocument and find elements using CSS selectors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I must convert an android app to iOS, this app uses deeply the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library and the [element.select(cssQuery)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) to find elements starting from CSS selectors.

Initially I wanted to convert selectors to XPATH and use xmllib2 but the css-selector usage is really pervasive (dozen of configuration files, already existing stored files)

Does exist some Cocoa code/library/framework able to create an HTML document and search using CSS selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if there is existing method to search using css selectors in Cocoa, but i here is an article about most common xml parsers for iOS:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Personally, i would recomend KissXML. It's DOM with support for XPath queries.

Comment: Thanks but if possible I need a library using css selectors starting from an HTML document (non necessary conforming to XML)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) wrappers. Gumbo is an html5 parser written by Google. Note that the CSS selectors that can be used are very simple and might not suit your needs.

- [ObjectiveGumbo](https://github.com/programmingthomas/ObjectiveGumbo)
- [OCGumbo](https://github.com/tracy-e/OCGumbo)

Hope this help (even if you already approved another answer).