# Why doesn't NSRegularExpression return index of matches?

Tags: jquery, regex, swift, cocoa, nsregularexpression

Let's say I wanted to iterate through the following HTML for a regex match:

```
<ul class="product_images">
    <li>
        <a data-style-name="keyword_1">
            <img>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-style-name="keyword_2">
            <img>
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I could use a parser like [Kanna](http://tid-kijyun.github.io/Kanna/) and a Block iterator method like `NSRegularExpression` to count each instance of `<li>` and return the index of the first match, which I could then use to simulate a mouse-click on the match element like so:

```
WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('product_images')[\(keywordIndex)].click()", completionHandler: nil)
```

But what about using a jQuery selector like `$("li:contains('keyword_2')")` instead? Coming from Python and JavaScript, I'm having trouble adjusting to Swift's syntax, and I feel like I'll be able to condense my functions with jQuery selectors. Most [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786559/reading-domdocument-and-find-elements-using-css-selectors) recommend using dependencies, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this natively in Swift — perhaps `NSSelectorFromString`? That said, if anyone more versed in the language could kindly point me in the right direction, I would much appreciate the help. An example of my code follows. Effectively, I'm having trouble getting a count for each `<li>` element; I'd like to click on the one that contains `keyword_2`.

#### Snippet

```
// Go to parent of match element and count each <li> element

func findKeyword() {
    var keyword = "keyword_2"
    var keywordIndex = 0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) { 
            self.browserView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.toString()", completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                if let HTML = html as? String {
                    let doc = try? Kanna.HTML(html: HTML, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    for string in (doc?.css("ul[class^='product_images']/li"))! {
                        if keyword(true, {$0 && string.text!.range(of: $1) != nil}) {
                            print("Found: " + string.text!)
                        }
                        keywordIndex += 1
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, so I'd edit the parameters of the function like so: `func FindKeyword(options: NSRegularExpression)`, correct?

Comment: @LeoDabus Got it. How do I now resolve the following error: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem! The issue was in my for loop — specifically, the first line:

```
for string in (doc?.css("ul[class^='product_images']/li"))! { ...
```

Here I'm using `string` when I should be using `keyword` because that's the string I'm looking for. I thus replaced `string` for `keyword` in the sequence above and everything worked smoothly.